# how can i plot this data from excel file?

Tags: plotting, excel

in this link i have two excel file that i want to plot them simultaneously but i can not do it. i want to draw files in one graph. 
i importing data by use of:
`s = Import["Example Data/population.xls"]`
but when i use `ListPlot` it draw a blank graph and i seriously confusing.
[link of my excel file](https://eesif.sharefile.com/d-s622733480c24756b)

Comment: Numbers are stored as text in your Excel file, so they are imported as strings. You need to convert them back to numbers. Try `s = ToExpression@Import["yourFile.xlsx"]` instead. Note also that `Import` automatically generates a list of lists from Excel files, one element per tab in the original file. You might want to extract the first part of what  `Import` returns, so `s = ToExpression@Import["yourFile.xlsx"][[1]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two files, and I took one of them.
Here is what I did:

```
In[12]:= top1 = 
  Import["<path to top1.xlsx"];

In[13]:= top1[[1, 1, 1]]

Out[13]= "-21.247643979057592"

In[14]:= Head[%]

Out[14]= String
```

Notice that the number is a string. Use ToExpression to get the strings converted into  Real Numbers.

```
In[15]:= top11 = ToExpression[top1];

In[16]:= top11[[1, 1, 1]]

Out[16]= -21.2476

In[17]:= Head[%]

Out[17]= Real

In[18]:= ListPlot[top11[[1]]]
```

Here is the plot I got:

[image]